# How to create an object during runtime in .net

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, binding

> There are 3 classes named Alpha ,Beta and Omega. Class Alpha and Beta inherits the Interface OInterface which has 2 functions called start and run. In the constructor of Omega Class we pass the value 1 or 2.

If the value is 1 I need to create the object of class Alpha or else object of Beta.
How can i do that?

Comment: Why you put "dynamic" and "binding" tags?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Omega
{
    private OInterface iDontKnowHowToNameIt;
    public Omega(int value)
    {
        if (value == 1)
            iDontKnowHowToNameIt = new Alpha();
        else if (value == 2)
            iDontKnowHowToNameIt = new Beta();
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong value passed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the methods of the interface declare that:

```
OInterface obj = null;

public Omega(int type)
{
    if(type == 1)
        obj = new Alpha();
    else if (type == 2)
         obj = new Beta();
    else
         throw new ArgumentException("Wrong type provided: " + type, "type");
}
```

Now you can use the methods where you need it, for example:

```
public void RunSomething()
{
    obj.Run();
}
```